# AWS sub-subdomain to point to subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

For reasons too complicated to explain in this question I have to create a sub-subdomain (for example: sub2.sub.domain.com) to point to the same subdomain (sub.domain.com).

I have tried using a CNAME pointing to the sub.domain.com and an A record pointing to the LB alias, neither of which seem to work.

Is this even possible and if yes, how can I do it in AWS?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't seem to work? Did you wait for it to propagate? Have you tried against AWS servers and not some other?

Comment: @JakubKania I get a `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error. I have, several days for both. The subdomain points to an AWS LB instance.

Comment: Use `dig` or `nslookup` not browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain was not fully migrated to AWS.